# Calculating distance between two points using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I don't understand why I have two different results between
Openlayers distanceTo () and [Movable Type Scripts](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

LatLng : **(43, 3)**
LatLng : **(42, 4)**
OL :  **187.6**
Movable Type Scripts : **138.1**

```
var Geographic  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); 
var Mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
var point1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(3, 43).transform(Geographic, Mercator);
var point2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(4, 42).transform(Geographic, Mercator);       
console.log(point1.distanceTo(point2)/1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

the "distance" depends on the reference system.

- When you work in Mercator or with other projected coordinate system, the distance is the straight line that join the two points on the plane where the data have been projected.
- When you work with lat/long coordinate, the distance will be the length of the smallest arc that joins the point.

the distortions of the distances can be huge. For instance, imagine that you want the distance between the points -179.99°,82° and  179.99°,82°. Those points are of course nearly side by side, but with the standard Mercator projection they will be separated by ~40000 km

Note that equidistant projections preserve the distance between a few special points and any other points.

Comment: Web Mercator projections (EPSG:3857 / 900913) aren't valid at the latitude's that you are describing.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't make sense to use it at this latitude (scale factor tends to infinity), but it "exists". Anyway, this was just an example and I took a maximum distortion to illustrate the risk of distance calculation with projected coordinate systems. I've replaced 89 by 82 (which doesn't affect the reasoning)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString` with those 2 LatLngs and use `getGeodesicLength` to get the correct length of that line.

The distance is dependent on how far this line is from the Equator, and should use Vincenty algorithm to correctly calculate the distance (since the earth is not flat)

```
  const line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(p1, p2);
  const distance = line.getGeodesicLength()
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out this question: [OpenLayers 3: How to calculate distance between 2 points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071490/openlayers-3-how-to-calculate-distance-between-2-points/26613832)